# What is different between cpu vs. requests.memory, pods vs. count/pods

Tags: kubernetes, quota

When I studying about [Resource Quotas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/), I found somethings very similar, e.g:

- `memory` vs. `requests.memory`
- `pods` vs. `count/pods`

So, my question is what's the different between them?

Comment: `count/pods` is specific to the ResourceQuotaSpec API.  `requests.memory` is the amount of memory you are informing the scheduler a Pod container will take (ResourceRequirements API).  Can you point to specific examples you are comparing against? The generic terms are used in many places. If you can give an example for each with an API response (like a `kubectl` command) it will be more easily answerable, or at least quote the section of the docs you are comparing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing Compute Resource Quota with Object Count Quota

- Compute Resource Quota

The total sum of compute resources that 
can be requested in a given namespace.

`requests.memory` - for instance you can set in this way the total guaranteed amount of memory for Dev team in their dev namespace taking into account all Pods' containers.

- Object Count Quota

The total number of generic objects that can exist in the namespace.

`count/services or pods` - possible use case, limit the maximum number of pods per namespace, quoting the official documentation:

> You might want to set a pods quota on a namespace to avoid the case where a user
>   creates many small pods and exhausts the cluster’s supply of Pod IPs.

Comment: Yes. I'm not confusing Compute Resource Quota with Object Count Quota.
I'm confusing between `memory` and `requests.memory`, both are Compute Resource Quota, right?

Comment: Ohh, I see now, then yes, `requests.memory` and `memory` are both examples of Compute Resource Quota, proof here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/d1031b18fc83146dd8418c17df289d09d10d29e5/pkg/quota/v1/evaluator/core/pods.go#L45
You are right the official documentation needs improvement here, as it does not explain differences between these two types of podResources.